# ColorAnimation change color in rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I want change rectange color, but, color doesn't change. Where is problem?

```
ColorAnimation col = new ColorAnimation();
col.From = Colors.Aqua;
col.To = Colors.PaleGreen;
col.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

Storyboard zgo = new Storyboard();
Storyboard.SetTarget(col, c);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(col,
           new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));
zgo.Children.Add(col);
zgo.Begin();
```

And here is XAML:

```
<Rectangle Name="rec"
    Height="100" Width="200"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Stroke="Black"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="rec_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="c"></SolidColorBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the animation directly by calling [`Animatable.BeginAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590761.aspx):

```
var colorAnimation = new ColorAnimation(
    Colors.Aqua, Colors.PaleGreen, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

c.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, colorAnimation);
```

---

You could still do it with a Storyboard by using the Rectangle as the animation's target and `Fill.Color` as target property::

```
Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
Storyboard.SetTarget(colorAnimation, rec);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorAnimation, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));
storyboard.Children.Add(colorAnimation);
storyboard.Begin();
```